# Where is Java hiding on my PC?

Tags: windows, java, uninstall

In my efforts to root out the mysterious Java 1.5.0_11 installation I have hiding somewhere on my PC, I completely uninstalled Java.

Now, a search in Explorer turns up nothing, but on the command prompt, if I type "java", it's still there.

If I type `java -version` it says `java version 1.5.0_11`.

How do I find it?

Comment: Type echo %PATH% in command promt and search for java installation path

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930383/jre-installation-directory-in-windows

Comment: check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678520/javac-not-working-in-windows-command-prompt

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `where java` to find out where it is. Or

```
for %x in (java.exe) do @echo %~$PATH:x
```

Usually it resides in %ProgramFiles%\Java, though.

Comment: This is easily the best way to do this on windows I have seen.

Comment: Wow... thank you... that really did the trick! Plus I learned you can for loops on the command line!

Comment: Well, that's not really a loop. It's just necessary because you cannot use the `%~$VAR:x` trick without a `for` variable (or a numbered argument in a batch file or subroutine).

Answer (score 2):

If you're under `Windows`, launch Java, go into `Task Manager`, right click on the `java.exe` process, "`Open File Location`". This should locate it.

Answer (score 1):

Do a file search for java.exe.